# How to create a direct line call to bot running on localhost

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am developing a bot locally. I want to use the bot on my .NET MVC application, I was trying to use BotFramework-WebChat. I alse found a offline-directline package to run direct line offline.

Offline-Directline Guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline

I am running a Directline locally using following command:

```
C:\Users\vrpinnin>directline -d 3000 - "http://localhost:3978/api/bot/conversations"
Listening for messages from client on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Routing messages to bot on http://localhost:3978/api/bot/conversations
```

Now I am trying to access the directline

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: '',
            token: '',
            domain: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
            webSocket: false,
            pollingInterval: 2000
        }),
        styleOptions: {
            rootHeight: '100%',
            rootWidth: '30%'
        }
    }, document.getElementById("chatbot"));
```

webchat.js:1 OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:3000/conversations 404 (Not Found)

But my webchat is getting redirected to URL http://127.0.0.1:3000/conversations

My goal is to connect my application to bot through webchat.
Please provide a solution even if it can be achieved without directline.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you're trying to solve here. Why not just create an ordinary bot in Azure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart

Comment: 1. If you're using the `offline-directline`, you need change the `domain` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/directline`. 2. But be aware that none of these packages are official releases.  3. Since this package doesn't support websocket/security token/attachment, for local test purpose, I decide to create [my own implementation](https://github.com/newbienewbie/InDirectLine) several days ago.

Comment: Hello @itminus . First of all, thank you for your contribution. One question, can the **"bridge"** you created be used in a production environment or is it only for development purposes?

Comment: @MrDave1999 That's only a POC for learning the directline protocol. It's for local testing purpose ,i.e., not production ready.

Comment: @itminus What else is missing from your implementation to make it production ready?